# Не могу интегрировать запрос на свой сервер

Tags: node.js, express, cors

Работаю с js не так давно. Нужно сделать 3rd party service - запрос на сторонний сервис. Он выполняет функцию генерации пароля.

Попробовал сделать запрос по примеру который нашел в интернете:

```
const https = require('https')
const options = {
  hostname: 'www.passwordrandom.com',
  port: 443,
  path: '/query?command=password',
  method: 'GET'
}
 
const req = https.request(options, res => {
  console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
 
  res.on('data', d => {
    process.stdout.write(d)
  })
})
 
req.on('error', error => {
  console.error(error)
})
 
req.end()
```

Он работает и генерирует пароль, однако не знаю как подключить к своему серверу. Вот моя попытка

```
router.get('/generate', Auth, async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get('https://www.passwordrandom.com/query?command=password')
        const password = await response.data;
        res.json(password)
        
    } catch (e) {
        res.status(500).json({message:'Error'});
    } finally{
        next()
    }
})
```

Фронт часть

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { AuthContext } from '../context/AuthContext';
import { useHttp } from '../hooks/http.hook';
import { useMessage } from '../hooks/message.hook';
import { useContext } from 'react';
 
export const UpdatePage = () => {
    const {userId, token} = useContext(AuthContext)
    const message = useMessage()
    const {request, error, clearError}=useHttp()
    const [oldpassword, setOldPassword] = useState('')
    const [newpassword, setNewPassword] = useState('')
 
    useEffect( () =>{
        message(error)
        clearError()
    }, [error, message, clearError])
 
    const updateHandler = async () => {
        try {
                const data = await request('/api/auth/update', 'POST', {userId ,oldpassword, newpassword}, {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`})
                message(data.message)
        } catch (e) {}
    }
 
    const generateHandler = async () => {
        try {
                const newpassword = await request('/api/auth/generate', 'GET', null, {Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`})
                setNewPassword(newpassword);
                //message(data.message)
        } catch (e) {}
    }
    
    return (
        <div className= "row">
            <div className='col s8 offset-m2'>
                <div className="card amber darken-4">
                    <div className="card-content white-text">
                        <span className="card-title">Update password</span>
                            <div className="input-field">
                                <p>Old Password</p>
                                <input placeholder="Old Password" id="oldpassword" type="text" name="oldpassword" className="white-input" onChange={e => setOldPassword(e.target.value)} value={oldpassword} />
                                <p>New Password</p>
                                <input placeholder="New Password" id="newpassword" type="text" name="newpassword" className="white-input" onChange={e => setNewPassword(e.target.value)} value={newpassword} />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="card-action">
                        <button className='btn grey darken-3' onClick={updateHandler} style={{marginRight: 10}}>Update</button>
                        <button className='btn grey darken-2' onClick={generateHandler}>Generate</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    )
}
 
export default UpdatePage
```

Comment: Попытка - это хорошо. А в чем суть вопроса? Ошибка, или что-то не то делает?

Comment: Если запустить код, который написан по примеру с помощью "node index.js", то все работает. Но мне нужно чтобы при нажатии кнопки выполнялась генерация нового пароля. При запуске с моей попыткой подключения (второй образец кода) выводит ошибки: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
 и ошибку
Cannot GET /api/auth/generate

Comment: _Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0_ означает, что запрос вернул не json, а html

Comment: вместо `res.json(password)` пошлите `res.send(password)` (или `res.json({ password })` но тогда нужно адаптировать вызов setNewPassword(newpassword))

Comment: а при чём тут cors?

Comment: Я попробовал помменять на res.send(password), однако ошибка не пропала

Comment: потому что то, что отправляет вам сервер является строкой, а не json

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, это можно как-то изменить?